# UICollectionView binding in Xamarin.iOS with Mvvm light

Tags: ios, mvvm, xamarin

Is there any way to bind `UICollectionView` to data  in iOS  with **Mvvm ligh**t?  Because I have found only `ObservableTableViewController`. Nothing similiar for `UIcollectionViewController`.